Oxygen concentrations in the air and absorption rates at sea, even under windy conditions
If I measure the amount of oxygen in the air at sea, is it the same as if I measure it on land?
What if there is wind?
Does oxygen concentration, change, in the middle of wind?
What about the ability of the body to absorb oxygen in windy conditions? Does that change? Does, the, absorption rate, change?
How can we measure these things?
